# Laravel 8 how to add string as column to Model::select() method

Tags: select, eloquent, laravel-8

I need to have some string constant in select result so in pure sql it could look like

```
select name, created_at, 'event' as type from events
```

It is necessary to enclose the string by single quotes and it works.

I try to write it in Laravel 8 like

```
Event::select('name', 'created_at', "'EVENT' as type")
```

But it does not work. Laravel parses the value to "'EVENT'" as "type"

Is it possible to write string value in select result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.raw()` for this purpose, like

```
Event::select('name', 'created_at', DB::raw("'EVENT' as type"))
```

Comment: Where is my previous comment? So thank you again.